# When will Windows 10 support end?

Tags: windows-10, html

I will install Windows 10 because the Windows 12 is a beta version. But i can't when will support end. I want install a stable version or other version like this.

Comment: Windows 12 is not a legitimate version of Windows, beta or otherwise. Microsoft has repeatedly stated that Windows 10 is the "last" version of Windows, which will get continual security and feature updates, indefinitely.

Comment: Windows 12 is an urban myth.

Comment: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2020/04/29/windows-12-rumors.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [Microsoft's website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-12/f164a9c8-4667-46d2-b439-647dc9fac591) we can see Windows 12 is not a legitimate replacement to Windows 10 if it is even being developed by Microsoft at all. Windows 10 will seemingly be supported forever as of current information.